# Multiple keywords with name XYZ found. Give the full name of the keyword you want to use - Robot Framework library issue

Tags: robotframework

i am running some tests in RF, via Copado Robotic Framework.
When running tests i encounter this error:
**Multiple keywords with name 'GoTo' found. Give the full name of the keyword you want to use:
Or the same with 'ClickElement' found error.**

I have the **KW Set Library Search Order** in place, but its not working properly.
I have also found this code snippet which should be placed somewhere, but i dont know where or will it solve anything: **"robot.lint.keywordResolvesToMultipleKeywords": false.**
Has anyone faced a similar issue before and is there a solution for it?
Thanks all!

```
*** Settings ***
Resource               ../../../resources/common_ecomm.robot

Library               QWeb
Library               QForce 
Library               OperatingSystem
Documentation         CJDB - CHCK - MADD - Checkout - Add-on Overview
Suite Setup           Setup Browser
Suite Teardown        End suite
Default Tags          sprint4

*** Test Cases ***

Verify "Add-ons" page overview
  
    QWeb.Appstate            Ecomm storefront      ${user_with_orders}    ${exp_pwd16}
    Set Library Search Order     QWeb     QForce   
    Sleep                        5      
    GoTo                     ${ecomm_purchase_journey}${stockID_list}[3]
    #Navigate to add-on page
    ClickElement             xpath\=//button[contains(@class,'partex-button skip-step')]
    ClickCheckbox    xpath\=//input[@value\='Cash']    on    anchor=Pay In Full
    ClickElement    xpath\=//div[@class\='container css-ixzd5']//button[1]
    ClickElement    xpath\=//div[@class\='css-ue32oj']//button[1]
```

I tried adding the "robot.lint.keywordResolvesToMultipleKeywords": false in my tests but with no luck.

Comment: Post the code, not the image.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the linter check does not fix the error. You should prefix your keyword with the name of the resource file or library you are using.

For example, if you want to run goto keyword from QWeb:

```
    QWeb.Goto   $yoururlhere
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there are many lines of code that need to be changed with this method. I was thinking about some "global" change that can be done. Also, do you know where should i disable the linter check? Somewhere in the Settings area, i assume?

Comment: Find out what that other resource / library is that exports the keyword with the same name and do not include it in that suite